Expansion in place
Background
I'm calculating complicated and huge terms that I need to integrate three times w.r.t. to three angles. My ansatz was to expand the terms, manually sort them into a 3D association and finally store the constant terms. Example:
myAssoc[Sin[x]Cos[x]] [Cos[y]] [Sin[z/2]] = constant terms

I can then integrate each key only once and in parallel, do also do stuff like simplifications or other operations.
While all that stuff works fine, the most recent problem was the expansion itself. Even though I have 64GB of Ram, it just doesn't fit into memory. And even though an upgrade to 128 could fix it, I have even huger terms waiting which most likely will not fit.
However, there's no reason to hold it all in memory, I just need to visit all nodes and store them to the association.
Code
This code does not expand Powers (because they dont appear in my expressions).
Clear[myExpand]
myExpand[node_Plus, factors_, func_] := 
 List @@ (myExpand[#, factors, func] & /@ node)
myExpand[Times[Plus[a_, b_, c___], Plus[d_, e_, f___], g___], 
   factors_, func_] :=
  With[{l1 = List[a, b, c], l2 = List[d, e, f]},
   Table[
    myExpand[lhs rhs g, factors, func],
    {lhs, l1},
    {rhs, l2}
    ]
   ];
myExpand[Times[a_, b_, c__], factors_, func_] := 
 myExpand[Times[a, c], b factors, func]
myExpand[Times[a_, b_Plus], factors_, func_] := 
 myExpand[b, a factors, func]
myExpand[Times[a_, b_Plus, c__], factors_, func_] := 
 myExpand[b c, a factors, func]
myExpand[a_, factors_, func_] := func[factors a]

Tests
Clear[save]
save[expr_] := AppendTo[list, expr]

compare[expr_] := Block[{expanded},
  list = {};
  myExpand[expr, 1, save];
  list = List @@ Plus @@ Flatten@list;
  expanded = List @@ Expand[expr];
  list == expanded
  ]

testExpressions = {
   2 x + 3 a (b + c),
   12 x y z (4 (b - c + 9/2 x))/(2 x^2 - y^2),
    (a + b + c) (d + e + f),
   (a + b + c) (4 (b - c + 9/2 x))/(2 x^2 - y^2),
   x y (e + f) z A B (g + h (i + j)),
   x y (e + f) z A B ((p + q + r) (-s - t + u)) ww vv
   };

compare /@ testExpressions

{True, True, True, True, True, True}

Concerns
Even though it passes all my test cases, I'm wondering if there is still a bug in here?
I'd say my Wolfram skill is somewhere around 4-6 / 10, so this code can be written more idiomatically. I yet have no idea how this is performanent-wise but if there is an obvious "don't do that", I'm open for suggestions :)
Finally, I stated the introduction in case this is an XY problem and there is a better solution altogether.
